# Vue separate counter

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, counter

I'm new to Vue and I am trying to make a component were a user has to divide 10 points over 4 statements. It looks like this:

[image]

If a user clicks on a circle, it will fill and add +1 to a counter. The problem is the counters are all linked. My question is thus: How do I make a separate / independent counter for each statement?

The data in qa contains 4 statements in json with a view properties I later need to bind to the input that are passed to the component via a prop.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
<div class="counter">
    <span>Je mag nog {{ total.counter }} punten verdelen</span>
    <div class="row" v-for="n in qa[0]">
        <div class="col s4">   
            <h5>{{ n['title'] }}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col s7">
            <span v-for="n in fullCounter"><img v-on:click="subtractCounter" class="circle-image" src="/images/solid-circle.png"></span>
            <span v-for="n in emptyCounter"><img v-on:click="addCounter" class="circle-image" src="/images/empty-circle.png"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col s1">
            <input v-model="fullCounter" type="number" min=0 max=10>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
let total = {
    counter: 10
}
export default {
    props: ['qa'],
    data() {
        return {
                total,
                fullCounter: 0,
                emptyCounter: 10, 
        }
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    methods: {
        addCounter: function () {
            if(this.fullCounter <= 10 && total.counter > 0) {
                this.total.counter -= 1,
                this.fullCounter += 1,
                this.emptyCounter -= 1
            }
        },
        subtractCounter: function () {
            if(this.emptyCounter >= 0) {
                this.total.counter += 1,                   
                this.fullCounter -= 1,
                this.emptyCounter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: 
here is a GA example: 
    { 
     "id": 600226, 
     "customer_id": 1, 
     "survey_id": 600006, 
     "user_id": 1, 
     "section": 1, 
     "pos": 2, 
     "title": null
     "Company 1", 
     "required": 0, 
     "subtitle": null
    }

Comment: I'm not so clear with your question.

Comment: Can you point me to the part were its unclear? I have: 3 shared counters. I need: 1 shared counter, 2 seperate counters.

Comment: If you want fullCounter and emptyCounter to be scoped, then you need to create a component for each statement.

Comment: Thanks Bert, you pointed me in the right direction. I figured it out!